# deleteOne() not deleting an array in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to write a customer management system but am having problems when posting a new company. I want the code to delete a company already on the DB based on a condition, the post the new company. It posts the new company but deleteOne() for some reason doesn't work.

the selectedCompany variable is a string and has a company name, as shown below the selectedCompany is passed into the Back End and seems to be doing everything right.... but its not working. Any ideas why it isn't working and what I can do?

Front End:

```js
const saveCompany = () => {
  const requestBody = {
    ...tempCompany,
    nameToRemove: selectedCompany
  };

  fetch("urlNameHere/register", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(requestBody)
  })
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data))
  .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
}
```

Back End:

```js
app.post("/register", async (request, response) => {
  const removedCompany = request.body.nameToRemove;
  const company = request.body;

  try {
    // Connect to MongoDB
    const client = await MongoClient.connect(process.env.DB_URL || 'your-mongodb-connection-string', {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
    });

    // Get the database and collection
    const db = client.db("DBNAme");
    const collection = db.collection("CollectionName");

    const filter = { name: removedCompany };

    const remove = await collection.deleteOne(filter);

    const result = await collection.insertOne(company);

    // Close the connection
    client.close();

    response.status(201).send({
      message: "Object sent successfully",
      companies: result, // This will contain the user object as stored in MongoDB
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error sending object to MongoDB:", error);
    response.status(500).send({
      message: "Failed to send object",
      error: error.message,
    });
  }
});
```

As discussed above the code shows what I have tried and what I am expecting.

Comment: be sure that `selectedCompany` is identical to the one you're trying to remove (no leading or trailing whitespaces). you can try to `console.log` things to check if you're sending things correctly